# Ubuntu 20.04 freezing (18.04 didn't)

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, intel, freeze, thinkpad

since I upgraded to 20.04 my Laptop started freezing frequently (every 15-60 minutes). I already had that problem a few years ago when I had Windows installed on the Laptop. After Switching to Ubuntu 18.04 I had no problems with freezing any more.

Its an Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga 260 with Intel® Core™ i7-6500U CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4, Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 520 (SKL GT2), 8GB Samsung RAM, ...

What changed from 18.04 to 20.04 that could cause the problems. Maybe something 20.04 and windows have, that 18.04 doesnt?

Thx

```
ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions

ls: cannot access '/home/maximilian/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions': No such file or directory



ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions

total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Apr 23 09:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Mai  9 08:14 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 23 09:35 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr 23 09:35 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr 23 09:35 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com



sudo dmidecode -s bios-version

N1GET34W (1.11 )




free -h

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7,7Gi       2,8Gi       938Mi       1,4Gi       3,9Gi       3,2Gi
Swap:         2,0Gi       0,0Ki       2,0Gi




sysctl vm.swappiness

vm.swappiness = 60




grep -i swap /etc/fstab

/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: You may have a GNOME Shell extension problem. Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. Sorry for the long list, but it's all stuff I need to review. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: Hey @heynnema thx, I added all the log outputs :)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Your GNOME Shell extensions are fine. I forgot to ask for `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`, and I need the serial # of your computer to confirm exactly which BIOS update applies to you. Tell me briefly what apps you normally have running on your computer... including how many open tabs in your web browser.

Comment: @heynnema I added the command output to the question. Is it save to reveal my serial number publicly? Lenovo says its not, but its not in warrant anyway. When I enter the serial number on lenovo.com and check drivers&software -> BIOS/UEFI it says this under bios update:     BIOS Update (Bootable CD) 1.79 24 Dec 2019 25.6 MB Recommended

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynema thx for your help. I updated the bios yesterday evening. And so far the freezing problem seems to be resolved. Also thx for your advice on increasing the swap.

Comment: Good news! Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BIOS**

You have BIOS N1GET34W (1.11).

Current BIOS is N1GETA0W (1.79). Go to [here](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-yoga-series-laptops/thinkpad-yoga-260/downloads/ds105460) to download the newer version.

**swap**

Your /swapfile may be a bit small for your working environment. Let's increase it from 2G to 4G.

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 8G RAM and 4G swap
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```